Need help understanding degrees of freedom
I'm having a hard time understanding how degrees of freedom work.
Considering this random regression model:
$$Y_i = 2 + 3 x_i + \epsilon_i$$
I imagine using 4 datapoints.
I decided to select $$x_1 = 2$$ $$x_2 = 3$$
I reprsented this with these matrices
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 3\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2+3(2) \\ 2+3(3)\\2+3x_3\\2+3x_4\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}-6 \\-8\\-2x_3-2\\-2x_4-2\end{bmatrix}$$
Where the final matrix is the residual. (ex. the last entry of this final matrix was derived as x4 - (2 + 3x4)
So from what I know about degrees of freedom, these final two x3 x4 should be pre-determined as we should have 4 - 2 residual degrees of freedom.
The constraint for residuals is that their sum = 0. Therefore,
$$-2x_3-2 + -2x_4 - 2 = 14$$
However, this allows for one of the two to be selected completely independently? I think I'm doing something wrong because this doesn't align with what I know about degrees of freedom.

It's hard to see how DF might be relevant because there's nothing to be estimated in this model.

You said you "imagined 4 data points" and then named only 2.  Also, similar to @whuber's comment, "df" implies something that is free to vary. In regression, we start with the data and estimate a model, you've started with a model.

I still cannot make sense of this question, but hope that the duplicate thread might help resolve your concerns or at least help you reformulate this post more clearly.
